# sql server select from two tables as null or value

Tags: sql-server, join

This shouldn't be hard but somehow I am unable to make this work. So I have two tables: `Splanning_Buildings` and `Splanning_RoomData`. The primary key of OBJECTID in the Splanning_Buildings table is represented as Objectid_bldg in the Splanning_RoomData table.

What I need is to select all rows from the Splanning_Buildings table in such a way that if its value is found inside the Splanning_RoomData table then show the value as "Existing" string; but if not found in Splanning_RoomData then show as blank.

This is SQL Server 2012.

Here is my sql:

```
SELECT t1.objectid, name, t2.building_n  FROM splanning_buildings t1 LEFT JOIN splanning_roomdata t2 ON t1.objectid = t2.objectid_bldg WHERE t2.objectid_bldg IS NULL

SELECT t1.objectid, name, t2.building_n  FROM splanning_buildings t1 LEFT JOIN splanning_roomdata t2 ON t1.objectid = t2.objectid_bldg
```

The first query returns all rows from the splanning-buildings table except the row which exists the splanning_RoomData table; so t2.building_n is 'null'. Makes sense.

The second query returns all rows from the buildings table but multiple t2.buildings_n rows.

None of these are the desired results! I guess I need some kind of sql Case() function?

Any idea?
Thanks!

Comment: So if I understand correctly, you want to show all the buildings and show the word "existing" if they have at least one associated room.  Is that correct?

Comment: Yes. Or blank if not existing. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  SELECT t1.objectid, name,
        CASE WHEN (EXISTS(SELECT TOP(1) 1 FROM splanning_roomdata t2 WHERE     t1.objectid = t2.objectid_bldg )) THEN 
        'Exists'
        ELSE 'Not exists' END AS [status]
    FROM splanning_buildings t1
```

Comment: Thanks...going to try

Comment: Works on first try. Thanks!

Comment: Question: How can your code show as a column like 'status'? Currently, it outputs as 'Column1' and I want to actually use a column in an asp.net application. Thanks.

Comment: You can leave the `top(1)` clause out of your query since `exists` accepts any amount of columns and rows.

Answer (score 0):

```
select objectid, 
  (select top 1 1 from room_data 
   where objectid_bldg=objectid) 
  as roomdata_exists from buildings
```

I simplified your table names a little bit - hope you can still make sense of it. ;-)

Comment: select objectid, name  (select 1 from splanning_roomdata    where objectid_bldg=objectid)   as roomdata_exists from splanning_buildings

Comment: Hmmm, too late now anyway, but there should not be the `name` in your select. My query *does* work in principle though, see here http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/337479/exists